# String equation error checker not working

Tags: java, error-handling, calculator

I have a method that checks to see if an equation written is correct.

This method check for:

- Multiple Parentheses
- Excess operators
- Double Digits
- q's
- and any character in a string that is not and of these:

.

```
private static final String operators = "-+/*%_";
private static final String operands = "0123456789x";
```

It was working fine, but then I added in modular to the operators and now whenever my code reaches the part in the method that checks to the left and the right of an operand to see if it is neither the end of the string or the beginning I get an error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
```

My method and all it's additional methods.

```
private static final String operators = "-+/*%_";
private static final String operands = "0123456789x";

public Boolean errorChecker(String infixExpr)
{
    char[] chars = infixExpr.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i<chars.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(infixExpr.charAt(i));
        if (isOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i)))
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == infixExpr.length())
            {
                out.append(infixExpr.charAt(i));
            }
            else if (isOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i + 1)) && isOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i - 1)))
            {
                System.out.println("To many Operators.");
                return false;
            }
            else if (isOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i + 1)))
            {
                if (infixExpr.charAt(i) != '-' || infixExpr.charAt(i + 1) != '-')
                {
                    System.out.println("To many Operators.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (isOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i - 1)))
            {
                if (infixExpr.charAt(i) != '-' || infixExpr.charAt(i - 1) != '-')
                {
                    System.out.println("To many Operators.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (isOperand(infixExpr.charAt(i)))
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == infixExpr.length())
            {
                out.append(infixExpr.charAt(i));
            }//THE LINE RIGHT BELOW THIS COMMENT THROWS THE ERROR!!!!!
            else if (isOperand(infixExpr.charAt(i + 1)) || isOperand(infixExpr.charAt(i - 1)))
            {
                System.out.println("Double digits and Postfix form are not accepted.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (infixExpr.charAt(i) == 'q')
        {
            System.out.println("Your meow is now false. Good-bye.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else if(infixExpr.charAt(i) == '(' || infixExpr.charAt(i) == ')')
        {
            int p1 = 0;
            int p2 = 0;
            for (int p = 0; p<chars.length; p++)
            {
                if(infixExpr.charAt(p) == '(')
                {
                    p1++;
                }
                if(infixExpr.charAt(p) == ')')
                {
                    p2++;
                }
            }
            if(p1 != p2)
            {
                System.out.println("To many parentheses.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid character.");
            return false;
        }
        out.append(infixExpr.charAt(i));
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isOperator(char val)
{
    return operators.indexOf(val) >= 0;
}

private boolean isOperand(char val)
{
    return operands.indexOf(val) >= 0;
}
```

My main portion that runs the method:

```
    Boolean meow = true;
    while(meow)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter infix expression: ");
        infixExpr = scan.next();//THE LINE RIGHT BELOW THIS COMMENT THROWS THE ERROR!!!!!
        if(makePostfix.errorChecker(infixExpr) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Converted expressions: "
                    + makePostfix.convert2Postfix(infixExpr));
            meow = false;
        }
    }
```

It was working fine before, but now it won't even pass 1+2 which was previously working and I changed NONE of that you see. What's wrong!?!?

Comment: which line throws given exception ? and don`t forget to give us input data

Comment: 1+2 was the input I gave... The line that throws it is... *edited the code to show the lines*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What looks like what's happening is that you check for the character at index (i + 1) several times in your code. Lets say you input a string with a length of five characters. The program goes through and reaches the line:

```
else if (isOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i + 1)) && isOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i - 1)))
```

If i == 4, this will cause the code:

```
infixExpr.charAt(i + 1)
```

to throw an index error. 
In essance, you're checking for a character at index five (the sixth character) in a string with a maximum index index of four which is five characters in length. Also, your checking for

```
if(i==0 || i == infixExpr.length)
```

won't work as is. Maybe check for (i==infixExpr.length-1).

Comment: This worked. I did this before you got to me, BUT IT IS CORRECT SO UPVOTE!!! YAAAAAYYAYAYYAYAYAYY GOOD FOR YOU THAAAAAAANKS SMILEY FACE HEART!!!!